# ID de clientes OAuth 2.0 no funcionan cuando subo mi aplicación al servidor

Tags: c#

Tengo una *API*, donde hago uso de las librerías de *Google calendar*.

Con esto hago la autenticación, y en mi local esta corriendo y funcionando de manera correcta, pero al subir mi proyecto a un servidor, me da error al consumir mi método para crear eventos de *Google calendar*.

```
 string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("../credentials.json");
                
                using (var stream =
                 new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                    // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                    string credPath = "token.json";
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "user",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                    Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
                }
                // Create Google Calendar API service.
                var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = ApplicationName,
                });
```

**Este es mi credential.json**

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "205980305745-s45mjpu6ihivldc9iri4qqkve4um66e8.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "project_id": "abiding-topic-304320",
    "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
    "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_secret": "bUHvNrLfNifuo9RGgUqqJZgm",
    "redirect_uris": [ "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob", "http://resourcedevice.webhop.net" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Valida que en el servidor tengas ambos archivos, *credentials.json* y *token.json*.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error en tiempo de ejecución?